# Cocos2dx- how to box2d cannot move through each other?

Tags: cocos2d-x

player box2d

```
auto playerbody = PhysicsBody::createBox(sp->getContentSize());
        playerbody->setGravityEnable(false);
        //playerbody->setDynamic(false);
        sp->setPhysicsBody(playerbody);
```

item box2d

```
auto ItemBody = PhysicsBody::createBox(item->getContentSize());
            ItemBody ->setGravityEnable(false);
            ItemBody ->setDynamic(false);
            item->setPhysicsBody(ItemBody );
```

When moving, these 2 boxes can go through each other.How does this not happen?
sorry my bad english. many thank

Comment: How are you moving the player?

Comment: http://codepad.org/ZmL2d7V8 func update in player.cpp
http://codepad.org/cU2BGMU3  eventkeyboard and func update in helloworld.cpp

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a minimal complete verifiable example that does not rely on code hosted at an external link.

Comment: Whenever I press the key, I will change the value of the direct variable, I run sheduleupdate to update the value of the direct variable